# Is it possible to reference class property type?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a class:

```
class Todo {
    public id: number;
}
```

Is it possible to use class property as type reference (get number type), like:

```
interface Settings {
    selectedTodoId: Todo.id;
}
```

property `selectedTodoId` should be now checked for `number` type

Comment: I think you'd have to wait for https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606

Comment: Try `Todo['id']`.  Not sure why people are telling you it's not possible.  I can flesh that out to a real answer when I get to a proper keyboard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, using [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  The trick is to use bracket notation (`Todo['id']`) instead of dotted notation (`Todo.id`)  Dotted notation would be very convenient, and there is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12962) to allow this, but it isn't trivial to implement and would break existing code (it conflicts with namespacing), so for now the bracket notation is the way to go.

Here's how you do it:

```
class Todo {
    public id: number;
}

interface Settings {
    selectedTodoId: Todo['id'];
}
```

You can verify that `selectedTodoId` has type `number` as desired.

Hope that helps; good lcuk!